# Layout-list bitmap specific size

Tags: android, xml, bitmap, size, layer-list

I have a problem while trying to implement a layer-list xml file in which I just want to be a gray background with an image in the middle. The problem is that I want to fix the center image to 200dp (width and height). How can it be achieved? I have found that the only way is to use the paddings, but this does not allow me to fix the image to 200dp, independently of the screen... Is it possible to achieve?

Thank you,

The code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/gray_dark"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_rounded"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**Note:** 
The purpose is to use it as a theme's background in order to simulate a splash-screen (If done as an activity layout takes more time and does not look like a real splash-screen)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but maybe someone will find this answer useful.

To specify bitmap size, you can use this xml.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
> <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <item>
>         android:drawable="@color/gray_dark"/>
>     </item>
>     <item
>         android:height="500px"
>         android:width="500px"
>         android:gravity="center">
>         <bitmap
>           android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_rounded"/>
>           android:gravity="fill"/>
>     </item> 
> </layer-list>
> ```